# How to return result of code that runs asynchronously in angular function

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that if it ran synchronously would be no problem. But the image has to load and then the `width` and `height` are available. Note this is called from an expression in `ng-style` attribute which is trying to establish the css `background-size` property of the image depending on if it's portrait or landscape. *But this is a question about async; not about image sizes ;)* It's a background image, not an `img` tag. I create an `Image` on the fly just to get the dimensions.

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(data:' + image.MimeType + ';base64,' + image.Content + ')', 'background-size': backgroundSize(image)}"
```

```
  $scope.backgroundSize = function (image) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      return img.width >= img.height ? 'cover' : 'contain';
    };
    img.src = 'data:' + image.MimeType + ';base64,' + image.Content;
  };
```

As you can see I am trying to return a value from asynchonous code but this does not work. The `img.onload` line executes, then the `img.src` line executes, then the function just exits. I can't go back and return the data.

I posted my best work-around as an answer, but is there a more elegant or direct way?

Comment: I dont know whether it fits your requirement or not. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/ds2afmdt/)

Comment: @themyth92, in your example, which I can tell you put quite a bit of work into, the img.src is set in the compile phase and the data is available then. So it has plenty of time to resolve before the directive html is transcluded into the document. If the data was only available from binding, it looks like you're example would have the same problem my code has.

Comment: *"How to return result of code that runs asynchronously in angular function"* you don't. that is ***impossible***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Using Promises in AngularJS Views](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/), promises can be automatically resolved when returned to a view from a function, as long as you use `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)` in module config. However, this does not seem to work inside `ng-style`.

This answer is not a direct answer because the `$scope.backgroundSize` does not return the final answer to the caller and thus as far as I know can not be used as the expression in the `ng-style` attribute. I am hoping for a better answer where the `promise` would get resolved in place in the attribute. When I tried to use `$scope.backgroundSize` directly as the expression in the `ng-style` attribute, it did not work. I really want to use `$scope.backgroundSize.then()` and have `then()` just return my value!

I know about `$q` to apply that in this case. It would take a form like this:

```
$scope.backgroundSize = function (image) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        deferred.resolve(img.width >= img.height ? 'cover' : 'contain');
    };
    img.src = 'data:' + image.MimeType + ';base64,' + image.Content;
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

This would set me up for a call like this which is done in the controller:

```
$scope.backgroundSize(image).then(
  function(backgroundSize){
    image.backgroundSize = backgroundSize;
  }
);
```

and then my `ng-style` expression could be:

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(data:' + image.MimeType + ';base64,' + image.Content + ')', 'background-size': image.backgroundSize}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is about as good as it's going to get. *"have then() just return my value!"* ***not possible***

Comment: @KevinB, is there anything that would get it into one expression that can be evaluated? Like, `image.backgroundSize.then(function(backgroundSize){ return backgroundSize; })`?

Comment: Not like that. but, sometimes it seems angular can take a promise, and when the promise resolves, it'l use its value. but i haven't done that much to give details on it.

Comment: I don't see any reference to that in the docs, so, no idea what it does/how it works.

Comment: Ah, you're being sarcastic, ;)